# Angular : Data-Binding with Array as a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, data-binding

My question is, how do I pass an Array of items as a data-binding value?

In my case I give my angular component via @Input() an Array of IValues. 
But when I check the the @Input() variable that should've received the array it just prints out an Array of objects and not an Array of IValues eventhough I gave it the type IValues.

**Component (FoodListPage) with data:**

```js
export class FoodListPage implements OnInit {
  foods: IValues[]; // <-- My data to pass
  category: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.category = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.categoryName; 
    this.foods = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.values;
    console.log("food-list-data: ", this.foods);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**The html of the component FoodListPage**

```html
<ion-content>
  <app-header title="{{category}}"></app-header>
  <app-food-listing values="{{foods}}"></app-food-listing> <!-- Here I pass the value (array of IValues) -->
  <app-nav-button page="main-menu"></app-nav-button>
</ion-content>
```

**FoodListingComponent that should receive the value (array of IValues)**

```js
export class FoodListingComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() values: IValues[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("food-listing-data: ", this.values); //Console log (actual)
  }
}
```

Expected data: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] <-- Are all from type IValue 
Actual data: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] <-- Are just from the type "Object"...

Comment: What does `Array of objects and not an Array of IValues` mean?

Comment: @Eldar the array of objects really is just an array of type Object. But I want my array of type IValues, but somehow the data gets worse after transferring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below stackblitz, you need to pass non primitive types such as array and objects using the angular property binding `[values]="foods"` only then the type will be maintained.

```
<ion-content>
  <app-header [title]="category"></app-header><!-- changed here -->
  <app-food-listing [values]="foods"></app-food-listing> <!-- changed here -->
  <app-nav-button page="main-menu"></app-nav-button>
</ion-content>
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-to-child-communication-afj6cy)

Answer (score 0):

can you change

```
   this.foods = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.values;
```

to

```
   this.foods = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.values as IValues[];
```

I think the problem is not with the @input. Type is lost when you get the values from the route.

Comment: The route works fine, the data transfer via the data-binding is causing the issue I guess.